# Issues after upgrading Android Studio Gradle Plugin from 1.2.3 to 1.5.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to upgrade my Android project's Gradle Plugin in Android Studio from the version 1.2.3 to 1.5.0 (to be able to use the Vector Asset Studio). The problem is that after changing **classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'** to **classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'**

I'm getting errors like the PNG aren't correct, are corrupted. Simply [ProjectName:mergeDebugResources]. Changing the corrupted PNGs does nothing...

Any ideas? Thanks!

**EDIT 1**

The error I'm getting:

```
:app:mergeDebugResources
AAPT: libpng error: PNG file corrupted by ASCII conversion
AAPT: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: libpng error: Not a PNG file
AAPT: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: libpng error: IDAT: CRC error
AAPT: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: libpng error: PNG file corrupted by ASCII conversion
AAPT: libpng error: Not a PNG file
AAPT: libpng error: IDAT: CRC error
AAPT: libpng error: bad adaptive filter value
AAPT: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: libpng error: Not a PNG file
AAPT: libpng error: Not a PNG file
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
```

**EDIT 2**

Adding the following line compiles, but the APK from 16MB grows to 45MB

```
aaptOptions.setProperty("cruncherEnabled", false)
```

Comment: remove recently added drawable or mipmap images

Comment: I haven't added any drawables or mipmaps recently. I did one month ago.

Comment: Can you post specific error message?

Comment: see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=195047#makechanges